# How to change the default notification sound in iOS?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

In my app I reach to Settings UI and I need a way to let the user choose specific sound for local notifications.
I searched a lot but no avail.

In Android there is `RingtonePreference`, is there any equivalent for iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the sound file in your applications bundle and it should [valid iOS format sound](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/SupportedAudioFormatsMacOSX/SupportedAudioFormatsMacOSX.html) and set the notification sound name property to set your sound file name. For help to set sound name use following code.......

`notifcation.soundName = @"yourSoundName.Format"` // Ex: sound.m4a

Answer (score 1):

```
notification.soundName = @"blow.aiff"; //blow.aiff should be in main bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following may it help:

```
notification.soundName = @"Example.caf";
```

Make sure the sound file placed in your app’s bundle, is in the correct format and is under 30 seconds in length.

best practice is to convert it to .caf format.

To convert a file to `.caf`, open up terminal, go to where you have your sound stored and type in:

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@44100 -c 1 Example.wav Example.caf
```

**Edit:**
make sure you are implementing `application:didreceiveLocalNotification` in your app delegate.

Local notifications work on simulator, push notifications do not.

Comment: So, I changed the file but I can not hear any thing on simulator

Comment: I did all the work of notifications I can register notifications and display them, But I can not hear any sound @ronak

Comment: have you checked it in real device? @wajeeh

Comment: No, this is a part of the problem. I think I will work on real device.
I need a way to let the user change the notification sound to what he like @ronak

Answer (score 0):

```
notification.soundname = @"sound file name .extension"
```

and make sure your app is in background so you can hear sound.